# Scala Compiler Error: assertion failed: scala.<none>

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Has anyone seen this before? The error below happens when I build my Scala/Play project in Intellij. As you can see none of my code is part of the call-stack.

```
Error:scalac: Error: assertion failed: scala.<none>
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: scala.<none>

at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$AppliedTypeTree.<init>(Trees.scala:579)

at scala.reflect.internal.TreeGen.mkTupleType(TreeGen.scala:293)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.TreeBuilder.makeTupleType(TreeBuilder.scala:44)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$PatternContextSensitive$class.scala$tools$nsc$ast$parser$Parsers$Parser$PatternContextSensitive$$tupleInfixType(Parsers.scala:877)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$PatternContextSensitive$$anonfun$typ$1.apply(Parsers.scala:910)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$PatternContextSensitive$$anonfun$typ$1.apply(Parsers.scala:907)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.placeholderTypeBoundary(Parsers.scala:487)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$PatternContextSensitive$class.typ(Parsers.scala:907)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$outPattern$.typ(Parsers.scala:1995)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$outPattern$.argType(Parsers.scala:1996)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$PatternContextSensitive$$anonfun$types$1.apply(Parsers.scala:1042)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$PatternContextSensitive$$anonfun$types$1.apply(Parsers.scala:1042)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.tokenSeparated(Parsers.scala:761)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$PatternContextSensitive$class.types(Parsers.scala:1042)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$outPattern$.types(Parsers.scala:1995)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$PatternContextSensitive$class.typeArgs(Parsers.scala:924)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$outPattern$.typeArgs(Parsers.scala:1995)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$PatternContextSensitive$class.simpleTypeRest(Parsers.scala:963)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$outPattern$.simpleTypeRest(Parsers.scala:1995)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$PatternContextSensitive$class.simpleType(Parsers.scala:943)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$outPattern$.simpleType(Parsers.scala:1995)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$PatternContextSensitive$$anonfun$annotType$1.apply(Parsers.scala:930)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$PatternContextSensitive$$anonfun$annotType$1.apply(Parsers.scala:930)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.placeholderTypeBoundary(Parsers.scala:487)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$PatternContextSensitive$class.annotType(Parsers.scala:930)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$outPattern$.annotType(Parsers.scala:1995)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.startAnnotType(Parsers.scala:2017)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.readAppliedParent$1(Parsers.scala:2822)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.templateParents(Parsers.scala:2828)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.template(Parsers.scala:2855)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.templateOpt(Parsers.scala:2886)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$classDef$1.apply(Parsers.scala:2753)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$classDef$1.apply(Parsers.scala:2733)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.savingClassContextBounds(Parsers.scala:329)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.classDef(Parsers.scala:2733)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.tmplDef(Parsers.scala:2710)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.defOrDcl(Parsers.scala:2467)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.nonLocalDefOrDcl(Parsers.scala:2475)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$templateStat$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(Parsers.scala:3032)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$templateStat$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(Parsers.scala:3032)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.joinComment(Parsers.scala:702)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$templateStat$1.applyOrElse(Parsers.scala:3032)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$templateStat$1.applyOrElse(Parsers.scala:3027)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.statSeq(Parsers.scala:2959)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.templateStats(Parsers.scala:3026)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$templateStatSeq$1.apply(Parsers.scala:3013)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$templateStatSeq$1.apply(Parsers.scala:2990)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.checkNoEscapingPlaceholders(Parsers.scala:464)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.templateStatSeq(Parsers.scala:2990)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.templateBody(Parsers.scala:2919)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.templateBodyOpt(Parsers.scala:2926)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.template(Parsers.scala:2856)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.templateOpt(Parsers.scala:2886)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.objectDef(Parsers.scala:2775)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.tmplDef(Parsers.scala:2714)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.topLevelTmplDef(Parsers.scala:2695)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$topStat$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2.apply(Parsers.scala:2982)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$topStat$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2.apply(Parsers.scala:2982)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.joinComment(Parsers.scala:702)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$topStat$1.applyOrElse(Parsers.scala:2982)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$topStat$1.applyOrElse(Parsers.scala:2975)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.statSeq(Parsers.scala:2959)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.topStatSeq(Parsers.scala:2974)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$compilationUnit$1.topstats$1(Parsers.scala:3172)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$compilationUnit$1.apply(Parsers.scala:3178)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$compilationUnit$1.apply(Parsers.scala:3140)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.checkNoEscapingPlaceholders(Parsers.scala:464)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.compilationUnit(Parsers.scala:3140)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$SourceFileParser$$anonfun$parseStartRule$1.apply(Parsers.scala:146)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$SourceFileParser$$anonfun$parseStartRule$1.apply(Parsers.scala:146)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$parse$1.apply(Parsers.scala:354)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$parse$1.apply(Parsers.scala:354)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.parseRule(Parsers.scala:347)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$Parser.parse(Parsers.scala:354)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Parsers$UnitParser.smartParse(Parsers.scala:243)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.SyntaxAnalyzer.scala$tools$nsc$ast$parser$SyntaxAnalyzer$$initialUnitBody(SyntaxAnalyzer.scala:87)

at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.SyntaxAnalyzer$ParserPhase.apply(SyntaxAnalyzer.scala:99)

at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:430)

at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Global.scala:397)

at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Global.scala:397)

at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:743)

at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1174)

at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.run(Global.scala:397)

at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1625)

at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1610)

at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1605)

at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1703)

at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:126)

at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:102)

at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:27)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:102)

at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:48)

at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)

at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.IdeaIncrementalCompiler.compile(IdeaIncrementalCompiler.scala:28)

at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:25)

at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:64)

at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:22)

at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
```

The build was working fine previously so I wonder if it's an environmental issue.

Based on this PasteBin I know I'm not the first person to see this issue: http://pastebin.com/VtFy12UJ

Comment: What is progress of this issue? How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried compiling outside of Intellij to see if that fixed the issue?

It's probably because you have a tuple with more than 22 items. Relevant Scala ticket: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9572

Double check your code.